# GetxController is not subtype of GetxController

Tags: flutter, dependencies, widget, flutter-getx

I am currently working on Ecommerce App in which i put the bottom navigation at homepage with badge on each icon ,Here when i put cartItems counter badge on CartIcon with dependency injection of cartcontroller on homepage(I have tried both methods using Getbuilder and Obx) ,but as i also using bottom navigation have to navigate my app through cartscreen which also has cartcontroller dependency the following error shows up .it's like i can't put the same controller in parent and child widget in widgets tree.
PS:I have also tried Get.find() for cartscreen.
Here is the error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building Builder:

    type 'CartController' is not a subtype of type 'CartController' in type cast where
    CartController is from sourcepath/controllers/cartController.dart
    sourcepath/controllers/cartcontroller.dart:1
    CartController is from sourcepath/controllers/cartcontroller.dart
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far i have understood that you have two different controllers
One is **cartController** and other one is **cartcontroller** (note the camel casing) so technically you cannot cast them together. Please check that in your code.

Comment: Thankyou So much issue resolved ,It's looks kind of stupid because the first path with capital C Controller doesn't even exists .....